# Flutter command to export Unit testing Result

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, terminal

I am able to export unit testing report from Android Studio IDE. We have button to export in Android studio as below image

[image]

After clicking export button I will get a new dialog to select location of export and file type like below image

[image]

I need terminal command to do the export .

Terminal Command "flutter test" is just executing my test cases. I want to know the command for exporting unit test cases.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `--coverage` argument with `flutter test` and then can generate html file with `genhtml`

```sh
flutter test --coverage && genhtml coverage/lcov.info --output=/User/Desktop/coverage
```

This will create a `coverage` folder having the `index.html` file

The contents of `/User/Desktop/coverage` should look like this
[image]

Comment: Tanvar Where I can mention the path to export?

Comment: @Manimurugan flutter test will create `coverage` folder sibling to `lib` and the `html` file path can be specified by `--output` argument of `genhtml`

Comment: Tanvar Thanks a lot for the info. Can you please tell me full command with Path to export if path is '/User/Desktop'

Comment: Tanvar also coverage folder has only lcov.info file.

Comment: updated the answer to generate coverage file at path /User/Desktop

Comment: Tanvar Your command creates only coverage folder and lcov.info file inside coverage folder. Its not creating report in my desktop folder.

Comment: the `coverage` folder sibling to `lib` in your flutter project will only have `lcov.info` file. There will be a second folder `coverage` on path /User/Desktop which will contain the html and css files. Attaching the screenshot of this second folder contents. If this folder is not being created please attach the screenshot of command output when you run at your system

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214427/discussion-between-mani-murugan-and-shubham-tanwar).

Comment: this gives courage result output not the actual test results like how many passed ans how many failed.